# CollectionChanged event of ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection, this collection has 2 items (model), the model has Value as a property.

there is an event CollectionChanged for the collection, which suppose to fire when an item is changed, so I am expecting to see this event get fire when a model Value sets but I don't how model should be structured to fire that event?

I know that Model can have an event and when a Model is added a handler can be assigned to this event, but I want to know how CollectionChanged works for change of item in the collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CollectionChanged` will only be raised when a model *replaces* another in your collection. Property changes to a model that is already inside the collection will not raise it.

You will need to handle those with the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event, which your models must expose.

Answer (score 2):

It won't fire if a property within the element is changed, only if you assign a new "model" item to an index of the collection.

If you want WPF to update when you change a property value within your Model class, you need to make the model instances implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

A hack is to add a new element to the collection and remove it immediately.  That will raise the collectionchanged event.